# Posting model back to controller: one property is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new(ish) to .NET web development, trying to change things over to MVC 5 from *WinForms*.  I am having an issue with posting a part of my model object back to the controller.

I send the model to the view initially like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LookupWorkOrder(string workOrderNumber)
{
    var workOrder = getDirector().getWorkOrderInfo(workOrderNumber);

    if (workOrder == null)
    {
        Response.StatusDescription = string.Format("Invalid Work Order Number: {0}", workOrderNumber);

        return View("Error");
    }

    var thing = new LotAddModel() { workOrder = workOrder, quantity = 7 };

    return View("FoundWorkOrder", thing);
}
```

Here are the two models you will need to know about:

```
public class LotAddModel
{
    public WorkOrderInfo workOrder { get; set; }
    public int employeeId { get; set; }
    public string lotNumber { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class WorkOrderInfo
{
    public string workOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string salesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string itemNumber { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal quantity { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

    public List<WorkOrderLotNumber> lots { get; set; }
    public List<WorkOrderPuller> pullers { get; set; }
    public List<WorkOrderBuilder> builders { get; set; }
    public List<WorkOrderTester> testers { get; set; }
    public List<WorkOrderInspector> inspectors { get; set; }

    #region cTor

    public WorkOrderInfo()
    {
        // I don't want to do anything here
    }

    internal WorkOrderInfo(string workOrderNumber, MainWorkOrderInfo mainInfo, List<WorkOrderLotNumber> lots,
            List<WorkOrderPuller> pullers, List<WorkOrderBuilder> builders,
            List<WorkOrderTester> testers, List<WorkOrderInspector> inspectors)
    {
        this.workOrderNumber = workOrderNumber;
        this.salesOrderNumber = mainInfo.salesOrderNumber;
        this.itemNumber = mainInfo.itemNumber;
        this.description = mainInfo.description;
        this.quantity = mainInfo.quantity;
        this.status = mainInfo.status;

        this.lots = lots;
        this.pullers = pullers;
        this.builders = builders;
        this.testers = testers;
        this.inspectors = inspectors;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Everything goes into the view just wonderfully.  The properties within the `thing.workOrder` object display perfectly fine.

However, when I try to send that model back to the Controller with this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddLotNumber", "WorkOrderLotEntry"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.workOrder);
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.quantity); // just did this to test something

    <label for="employeeId">EmployeeID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="employeeId" ? />

    <label for="lotNumber">Lot Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lotNumber" />

    <input type="submit" value="Add Lot Number" />
}
```

Which hits this Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddLotNumber(LotAddModel model)
{
    /*
     *  model.quantity is equal to 7, just like it should be.
     *  model.workOrder is NULL --> THIS IS THE REASON I AM POSTING THIS QUESTION - why is it always null??
     *  
     */
    try
    {
        getDirector().addLotNumber(model.workOrder, model.employeeId, model.lotNumber, model.quantity);

        return View("FoundWorkOrder", model.workOrder);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Response.StatusDescription = exception.Message;

        return View("Error"); // I get this bad boy every time...
    }
}
```

Everything loads into the `model` object perfect, except for the `model.workOrder` property, which is constantly null.

I don't get why I cannot send that workOrder property back to the Controller.  I really want to be able to do this, or something similar at least.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model.workOrder
```

is a property of type `WorkOrderInfo` and the `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.workOrder);` does not know how to serialize it. Open chrome dev tools and inspect what you have in that hidden field. That is what is going to be posted back to the controller and if that can't be deserialized back to `WorkOrderInfo` you'll get `null`. Why not just do something like `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.workOrder.workOrderNumber)`? 
Then change

```
public class LotAddModel
{
    public string workOrderNumber{ get; set; }
    public int employeeId { get; set; }
    public string lotNumber { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
public class WorkOrderInfo
{
    public string workOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string salesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string itemNumber { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal quantity { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

    public List<WorkOrderLotNumber> lots { get; set; }
    public List<WorkOrderPuller> pullers { get; set; }
    public List<WorkOrderBuilder> builders { get; set; }
    public List<WorkOrderTester> testers { get; set; }
    public List<WorkOrderInspector> inspectors { get; set; }

    #region cTor

    public WorkOrderInfo()
    {
        // I don't want to do anything here
    }

    internal WorkOrderInfo(string workOrderNumber, MainWorkOrderInfo mainInfo, List<WorkOrderLotNumber> lots,
            List<WorkOrderPuller> pullers, List<WorkOrderBuilder> builders,
            List<WorkOrderTester> testers, List<WorkOrderInspector> inspectors)
    {
        this.workOrderNumber = workOrderNumber;
        this.salesOrderNumber = mainInfo.salesOrderNumber;
        this.itemNumber = mainInfo.itemNumber;
        this.description = mainInfo.description;
        this.quantity = mainInfo.quantity;
        this.status = mainInfo.status;

        this.lots = lots;
        this.pullers = pullers;
        this.builders = builders;
        this.testers = testers;
        this.inspectors = inspectors;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Well the main reason I don't want to use just the ID is because then i would need to look it up again.  We are running SQL Server 2000, I try to save time anywhere I can.  Is there any way to make it know how to serialize it?

Comment: You'll need to query anyway, have in mind that a malicious user may post anything he/she wants. The javascript validation may be disabled (remember they control their own browser) so that you may end up with some invalid data in the controller. You have to check this against the db to make sure everything is ok and if not return 403 or 500 or whatever error code you think is appropriate.

Comment: I looked at the value in dev tools as you suggested, and all it stores is the fully qualified name of the class?  So does that imply that you cannot send any complex data types back to the Controller class?  It looks like it just called `ToString()` on the object,

Comment: That is exactly what it is doing. OK you can solve your problem by overriding the ToString method and using JSON.NET you can seriallize the whole object as a string then return that string. But later on you'll have to deserialize back in the controller. I'll edit my answer to show you the code. BUT this is not the correct way of doing it. You're trying to implement some custom old ASP.NET ViewState (google that)

Comment: Yea I thought about using the JSON method, but just as you confirmed I did not think that would be a "correct" way to do it.  I will just switch it over to using the ID, if that is more correct way to do it.

Comment: It is indeed. As a rule of a thumb: Do not trust anything that is coming from the browser (think input parameters to controllers). You have to double check those before processing. Good luck :) and if you find that helpful you can vote up ;)